# ios wsdl2objc response error 500

Tags: ios, web-services, soap, wsdl, wsdl2objc

i am trying to make a request to a SOAP web service with the code below.

```
BasicHttpBinding_IGTBEihaleWSBinding *binding = [GTBEIhaleWSSvc BasicHttpBinding_IGTBEihaleWSBinding];
binding.logXMLInOut = YES;

GTBEIhaleWSSvc_IhaleListesiGetir *request = [GTBEIhaleWSSvc_IhaleListesiGetir new];

BasicHttpBinding_IGTBEihaleWSBindingResponse *response = [binding IhaleListesiGetirUsingParameters:request];

NSArray *responseHeaders = response.headers;
NSArray *responseBodyParts = response.bodyParts;
```

However, i am getting this error.

```
2014-02-21 11:33:36.348 Mobil Ihale Uygulamasi[22801:70b] ResponseStatus: 500
2014-02-21 11:33:36.349 Mobil Ihale Uygulamasi[22801:70b] ResponseHeaders:
{
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 449;
    "Content-Type" = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Fri, 21 Feb 2014 09:33:21 GMT";
    Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1";
}
2014-02-21 11:33:36.350 Mobil Ihale Uygulamasi[22801:70b] ResponseError:
Error Domain=BasicHttpBinding_IGTBEihaleWSBindingResponseHTTP Code=500 "internal server error" UserInfo=0x10923ce40 {NSLocalizedDescription=internal server error}
```

I don't have a problem with another SOAP service with this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem is about wsdl2objc's parsing. Something is wrong with the generated code. Thus, I found another tool named [Easy WSDL](http://easywsdl.com/). It just worked perfect for me.